# Embedding SharePoint List and Folder Content in an iFrame on my site

Tags: sharepoint, embed, frame

I have a task to embed SharePoint documents and the contents of a SharePoint folder on my website using an iframe.

So far, I've been successful with documents, using a URL like:

`https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/_layouts/15/embed.aspx?UniqueId=<id>`

The documents are displayed perfectly.

However, I am struggling to find a way to display the content of a folder or a list via iFrame.

My attempts to apply a similar approach as I did with the documents, unfortunately, have not been successful. I've scoured the documentation, but have not managed to unearth an answer.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!